# __eq__ order enforcement in Python

Tags: python, oop

*A slightly long question to sufficiently explain the background...*

Assuming there's a builtin `class A`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
```

It's expected to compare in this way:

```
a1, a2 = A(1), A(2)
a1 == a2  # False
```

For some reason, the team introduced a wrapper on top of it (*The code example doesn't actually wrap A to simplify the code complexity.*)

```
class WrapperA:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.pa = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.pa == other.pa
```

Again, it's expected to compare in this way:

```
wa1, wa2 = WrapperA(1), WrapperA(2)
wa1 == wa2  # False
```

Although it's expected to use either `A` or `WrapperA`, the problem is some code bases contain both usages, thus following comparison failed:

```
a, wa = A(), WrapperA()
wa == a  # AttributeError
a == wa  # AttributeError
```

A known solution is to modify `__eq__`:

For `wa == a`:

```
class WrapperA:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.pa = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.pa == other.a
        return self.pa == other.pa
```

For `a == wa`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, WrapperA):
            return self.a == other.pa
        return self.a == other.a
```

Modifying WrapperA is expected. For A, since it is a builtin thing, two solutions are:

1. Use setattr to extend A to support WrapperA.

```
setattr(A, '__eq__', eq_that_supports_WrapperA)
```

2. Enforce developer to only compare `wa == a` (And then don't care about `a == wa`).

1st option is obviously ugly with duplicated implementation, and 2nd gives developer unnecessary "surprise". So my question is, is there an elegant way to replace any usage of `a == wa` to `wa == a` by the Python implementation internally?

Comment: Note that ``==`` is generally expected to work across *all* types. ``A.__eq__`` *requiring* ``other`` to be an ``A`` is actually a bug that should be fixed. It should at the very least return ``NotImplemented`` when it cannot make a decision.

Comment: By "builtin thing", do you mean a [builtin type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) (or otherwise one from the standard library) or a third-party library type?

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, I suggest you have extensive amount of tests for both `A` and `WrapperA` so you know everything is still working when some day somebody introduces `WrapperWrapperA` and `BaseA`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The example is [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). Assuming we want to make a wrapper (e.g: `IPAddress`) and make it comparable with both `ipaddress.IPv4Address` and `ipaddress.IPv6Address`.

Comment: In that case I'm confused – the ``ipaddress`` classes seem to correctly return ``NotImplemented`` when ``other`` is not compatible. This means it should have been sufficient to modify "``WrapperA``".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Please do not confuse, because in SO I have to generalize the question to maximize the value for others with similar issues. Your comment and the answer by spectras explained the magic behind Python are very helpful and new to me. My top priority is to figure out if it's safe and sufficient with your explanation in my wrapper implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the comment from MisterMiyagi under the question:

> Note that == is generally expected to work across all types. `A.__eq__` requiring other to be an A is actually a bug that should be fixed. It should at the very least return NotImplemented when it cannot make a decision

This is important, not just a question of style. In fact, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented):

> **When a binary (or in-place) method returns `NotImplemented` the interpreter will try the reflected operation on the other type.**

Thus if you just apply MisterMiyagi's comment and fix the logic of `__eq__`, you'll see your code works fine already:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.a == other.a
        return NotImplemented


class WrapperA:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.pa = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.pa == other.a
        elif isinstance(other, WrapperA):
            return self.pa == other.pa
        return NotImplemented

# Trying it
a = A(5)
wrap_a = WrapperA(5)

print(a == wrap_a)
print(wrap_a == a)

wrap_a.pa = 7
print(a == wrap_a)
print(wrap_a == a)
print(f'{wrap_a.pa=}')
```

Yields:

```
True
True
False
False
wrap_a.pa=7
```

Under the hood, `a == wrap_a` calls `A.__eq__` first, which returns `NotImplemented`. Python then automatically tries `WrapperA.__eq__` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really like this whole thing, since I think that wrapping a builtin and using different attribute names will lead to unexpected stuff, but anyway, this will work for you

```py
import inspect


class A:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a


class WrapperA:
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.pa = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.pa == other.a
        return self.pa == other.pa

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        # Figure out who tried to get the attribute
        # If the item requested was 'a', check if A's __eq__ method called us,
        # in that case return pa instead
        caller = inspect.stack()[1]
        if item == 'a' and getattr(caller, 'function') == '__eq__' and isinstance(caller.frame.f_locals.get('self'), A):
            return super(WrapperA, self).__getattribute__('pa')
        return super(WrapperA, self).__getattribute__(item)

a = A(5)
wrap_a = WrapperA(5)

print(a == wrap_a)
print(wrap_a == a)

wrap_a.pa = 7
print(a == wrap_a)
print(wrap_a == a)
print(f'{wrap_a.pa=}')
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
False
wrap_a.pa=7
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ron Serruyas answer:

This uses `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`, where the first one is only called if the second one raises an AttributeError or explicitly calls it [(ref)](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattribute.html). This means if the wrapper does not implement `__eq__` and the equality should *only* be performed on the underlying data structure (stored in objects of class `A`), a working example is given by:

```py
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, internal_data=None):
    self._internal_data = internal_data

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self._internal_data == other._internal_data

class WrapperA(object):
  def __init__(self, a_object: A):
    self._a = a_object

  def __getattr__(self, attribute):
    if attribute != '_a':  # This is neccessary to prevent recursive calls
      return getattr(self._a, attribute)

a1 = A(internal_data=1)
a2 = A(internal_data=2)

wa1 = WrapperA(a1)
wa2 = WrapperA(a2)    

print(
    a1 == a1,
    a1 == a2,
    wa1 == wa1,
    a1 == wa1,
    a2 == wa2,
    wa1 == a1)

>>> True False True True True True
```